# Why express a matrix as a product of a singular matrix and another one

Tags: linear-algebra, singularity

I am reading a paper and it says that it's better to express a vector of a distribution $\boldsymbol{b}$ as a product of a singular matrix $\Lambda$ and a spherical distribution $\boldsymbol{u}$, that is, $\boldsymbol{b}=\Lambda\boldsymbol{u}$.

My question is: is there a obvious or any reason to do so?

Comment: Welcome to math-stackexchange. Can you please provide some more context to this question? Which paper are you reading? It is very hard to give a sensible answer with so little information given.

Comment: Presumably, the author finds it easier to work with $\mathbf u$, which has a spherical distribution, than to work with $b$, which would have an (ellipsoidal?) distribution.  As for what it is exactly that is easier to do using a vector with spherical distribution, we'd need the paper to figure that out.  Do you have a link?

Comment: It's the paper "Fitting Linear Mixed-Effects Models using lme4" https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v067i01

Comment: In the mixed models effects equation, there is a random variable distribution $\boldsymbol{b}$ multiplying the model matrix $\boldsymbol{Z}$. This product represents the random effects part of the model. It makes sense that it's easier to deal with a spherical distribution. But why does $\Lambda$ multiplying 
$\boldsymbol{u}$ should be singular?